# Docx to html conversion using docx4j v3

Tags: java, html, docx4j

HI i am trying to convert docx to html using docx4j V3.below is my code.

```
    File initialFile = new File("input/table_1.docx");
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(is);
    HTMLSettings htmlSettings = Docx4J.createHTMLSettings();
    htmlSettings.setWmlPackage(wordMLPackage);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("input/table_1.html");
    Docx4J.toHTML(htmlSettings, out, Docx4J.FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL);
    String result = ((ByteArrayOutputStream)out).toString();
    System.out.println(result);
```

This is the ERROR i am getting. I have used mvn to resolve jar dependency.can anyone help on this
ERROR:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Couldn't load xml
>   from stream   at
>   org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:504)
>     at
>   org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:302)
>     at
>   org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.load(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:170)
>     at org.docx4j.Docx4J.load(Docx4J.java:195)

Comment: looks like there is a problem with your input/table_1.docx.  Fix the path?

Comment: Yes i have varify that its right. I have am using mavan so jars also are fine . i am not finding this error on the google as well

Comment: either your docx can't be found, or it is broken.

Comment: Yeah its was file which had problem , thx it works :)

Comment: thanks for this question,  it was a solution to me !